# Bind function on Runtime for dynamically created html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to dynamically create a `<ul>` html element with a specific class, say `class_c`, using an ajax call.

`class_c` is used by a third party js file, which can neither be changed nor called manually as it is anonymous (like `$('.class_c').click(function(e){})`) so I can't bind using jQuery `.bind()`.

Is there a way to rebuild the binding for all the elements with `class_c`, so that the new element can respond to this anonymous function?

Comment: You mean you want to fire *their* handler, for new elements you add they they haven't hooked the event on?

Comment: I tried what you suggested ... didn't worked.Can you tell, if I can remove other classed attached to the cloned element (not class_c) and it will still have the dependency? Because their is action define for other classes on the element used to create clone.

Comment: Impossible to say without a fair bit more information. What you're trying to do, if I'm understanding you, is ***very unusual***, which typically means that you should consider a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

if you use on() instead of click(), you can bind the click handle to all child elements of your selector, even if those elements will be created in future. of course, you then need a container for those "to be created elements", that is already in the dom, or the handler still won't work...

```
$('.myContainer').on("click", ".class_c", function(e){});
```

Comment: That would let them hook up *their own* handler, but my read of the question is they want to fire the *other code's* handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to fire *their* handler, for new elements you add they they haven't hooked the event on, then other than hacking jQuery internals the only thing I can come up with is *cloning* one of the elements they've hooked the event on.

jQuery's `clone` method accepts an argument that tells it to clone events and data as well as just the node. So when adding the new element, you could do this:

```
var clone = $(".class_c").first().clone(true);
clone.html(/*...your content here...*/);
clone.appendTo(/*...some appropriate target...*/);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/besuje/2/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="class_c">
    <li>Original - click me!</li>
  </ul>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    // "Other" code hooks click on .class_c elements by *cloning* one of
    // the ones that already has the click event hooked, using the `true`
    // argument that tells jQuery to clone event handlers and data
    $(".class_c").click(function() {
      display("Handler triggered for '" + $(this).text() + "'");
    });

    // Your code adds a new .class_c element
    var clone = $(".class_c").first().clone(true);
    clone.html("<li>Clone - click me!</li>");
    clone.appendTo(document.body);

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```